# FetchingURL Using JSON on Google Sheets

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am attempting to use JSON to extract followers on Spotify Playlists.
It seems like various playlists have different HTML data - which makes it complicated.

Here's the code I have currently in Google Apps Scripts. (courtesy of @Tanaike)

```
function SAMPLE(url) {
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  const v = res.replace(/&amp;/g, "&").match(/Spotify\.Entity \=([\s\S\w]+?);/);
  return v && v.length == 2 ? JSON.parse(v[1].trim()).followers.total : "Value cannot be 
retrieved.";
}
```

Then I just used =SAMPLE(the link) in the cells

However, I am getting this error on some playlist links (I don't know why):
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input (line 4).

Examples of working links:
https://open.spotify.com/playlist/5aSO2lT7sVPKut6F9L6IAc
https://open.spotify.com/playlist/7qvQVDnLe4asawpZqYhKMQ

Examples of nonworking links (shows the error stated above)
https://open.spotify.com/playlist/2Um96ZbAH1fFTHmAcpO50n
https://open.spotify.com/playlist/68jtRFcWtaFNHKO5wYLBsk

About 80% of the links work (I have over 400). Any guidance or help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you everyone!

Comment: Here are more nonworking links: https://open.spotify.com/playlist/2phIYXF2hAd5gTj00IwXbU
https://open.spotify.com/playlist/7MBKSFzpPLQ9ryPtydXVwf https://open.spotify.com/playlist/148My4xA7WoEaNDmnl2A8Z https://open.spotify.com/playlist/4zMaYNXz2pP1OPGz9SIJhX
https://open.spotify.com/playlist/2hBohCkXzjzTLh6jtd7gUZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the number of followers from the following URLs.

  ```
    https://open.spotify.com/playlist/5aSO2lT7sVPKut6F9L6IAc
    https://open.spotify.com/playlist/7qvQVDnLe4asawpZqYhKMQ
    https://open.spotify.com/playlist/2Um96ZbAH1fFTHmAcpO50n
    https://open.spotify.com/playlist/68jtRFcWtaFNHKO5wYLBsk
    https://open.spotify.com/playlist/2phIYXF2hAd5gTj00IwXbU
    https://open.spotify.com/playlist/7MBKSFzpPLQ9ryPtydXVwf
    https://open.spotify.com/playlist/148My4xA7WoEaNDmnl2A8Z
    https://open.spotify.com/playlist/4zMaYNXz2pP1OPGz9SIJhX
    https://open.spotify.com/playlist/2hBohCkXzjzTLh6jtd7gUZ
  ```

#### Modification points:

- I think that in the current stage, all JSON data is retrieved and the data is parsed, and then, the value is retrieved. In this case, I thought that the specific characters might be included and those characters might occur the issue.

So in this answer, I would like to retrieve the part of value from JSON data and parsed it and returned value. The modified script is as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function SAMPLE(url) {
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  const v = res.match(/followers":({[\s\S\w]+?})/);
  return v && v.length == 2 ? JSON.parse(v[1].trim()).total : "Value cannot be retrieved.";
}
```

#### Result:

When above script is used for the above 9 URLs, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- This sample script is for the URLs in your question. So when you tested it for other URLs, the script might not be able to used. And, when the structure of HTML is changed at the server side, the script might not be able to used. So please be careful this.

### Updated on January 15, 2022:

It seems that the specification of the HTML data is a bit changed. So I updated the above script as follows.

#### Sample script:

```js
function SAMPLE(url) {
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  const v = res.match(/"followers":({[\s\S\w]+?})/);
  return v && v.length == 2 ? JSON.parse(v[1].trim()).total : "Value cannot be retrieved.";
}
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough for not only helping me figure it out but explaining everything. Works with all the links, thank you again for this!!

Comment: @Robert Brooks Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: It looks like the specification of the HTML has changed once again since 2/27/2022. Can you please take a look at this again? Thank you!

Comment: @Robert Brooks In that case, it is considered that the specification of the site was changed. It is required to analyze the new HTML data. So, in order to post the new answer for the new specification, can you post it as a new question? If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: Of course! Thank you and here it is - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71290197/fetchingurl-using-json-on-google-sheets-from-spotify