# FetchingURL Using JSON on Google Sheets v2

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a code in Google Apps Scripts that takes a Spotify URL and pastes the amount of followers in the cell where you reference the url. =SAMPLE(A2) (where A2 holds the URL)

It seems that the specification has changed again. And I'm not sure how to fix it. Any guidance or help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's the original post = [FetchingURL Using JSON on Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66271111/fetchingurl-using-json-on-google-sheets/66272198?noredirect=1#comment126012615_66272198)

Here's the code I have currently in Google Apps Scripts. (courtesy of @Tanaike)

```
function SAMPLE(url) {
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  const v = res.match(/"followers":({[\s\S\w]+?})/);
  return v && v.length == 2 ? JSON.parse(v[1].trim()).total : "Value cannot be 
retrieved.";
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: There's probably easier ways to do this using [Spotify's API process](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/). While it might seem overwhelming at first, using API's makes pulling information from sites far simpler.

Comment: @Tanaike Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current stage, it seems that the JSON data is put as base64 data, and also, the structure of the object was changed. So, as the current sample script, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function SAMPLE(url) {
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  const v = res.match(/<script id\="initial-state" type\="text\/plain">([\s\S\w]+?)<\//);
  if (!v || v.length != 2) return "Value cannot be retrieved.";
  const obj = JSON.parse(Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(v[1].trim())).getDataAsString());
  const value = Object.entries(obj.entities.items).reduce((n, [k, o]) => {
    if (k.includes("spotify:playlist:")) n.push(o.followers.total);
    return n;
  }, []);
  return value.length > 0 ? value[0] : "Value cannot be retrieved.";
}
```

#### Note:

- This sample script is for the current HTML data. So, I think that this might be changed in the future update. So, I also would like to recommend using the API for your future work as it has already been mentioned in the comment.

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike I will look into the API and keep everyone updated!

Comment: @devR Thank you for replying. If you have a question when you test the API, when you post it as a new question, it will help users including me think of the solution.

Comment: The function returns nothing. Do you have any suggestions on what to fix? Thank you so much! @Tanaike

Comment: @devR About `The function returns nothing. Do you have any suggestions on what to fix? Thank you so much!`, I would like to support you. I thought that in the current stage, the specification might be changed. So can you post it as a new question? By this, it will help users including me think of the solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike here's the new post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74868672/fetchingurl-using-json-on-google-sheets-v3