# Connecting Spotify API with Google Sheets

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spotify

I am trying to find a more stable way to extract Spotify Data into Google Sheets. I need a variety of data, such as (playlist followers/likes, artist followers, and monthly listeners.

Right now I have a way to do all of that. Using importXML and JSON. For reference - [FetchingURL Using JSON on Google Sheets v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73576034/fetchingurl-using-json-on-google-sheets-v2)

I want to use the Spotify API as a more reliable way to get these numbers. However, I am very stuck on how to even start. I have been looking at this website - https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#/ and I'm just not sure what to even do.

Any guidance or reference links would be very much appreciated!

Thanks,
Robert

Comment: First, I apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. About `I'm just not sure what to even do.`, can I ask you about the details of it? I thought that when I could correctly understand your current issue, I might be able to support you.

Comment: @Tanaike Your answer was super helpful, I am just trying to get this data through an API (which I have zero experience with). There seems to be a big learning curve, and I just need help getting started I am super confused while researching everything that needs to be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may start with knowing the general guides for Authorization with Spotify Web API as referenced [here](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/).

A Web Application is needed for this since most of the information you need to pull from Spotify API (e.g playlist followers/likes, artist followers, and monthly listeners.) is not a publicly available information for the base request URI.

Here is a sample of Client Credentials OAuth flow:

```
var request = require('request'); // "Request" library

var client_id = 'CLIENT_ID'; // Your client id
var client_secret = 'CLIENT_SECRET'; // Your secret

// your application requests authorization
var authOptions = {
  url: 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + (new Buffer(client_id + ':' + client_secret).toString('base64'))
  },
  form: {
    grant_type: 'client_credentials'
  },
  json: true
};

request.post(authOptions, function(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {

    // use the access token to access the Spotify Web API
    var token = body.access_token;
    var options = {
      url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/jmperezperez',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
      },
      json: true
    };
    request.get(options, function(error, response, body) {
      console.log(body);
    });
  }
});
```

You may login to your Spotify Developer Dashboard [here](https://developer.spotify.com/dashboard/) to generate your client ID and client secret upon creating an application environment for the needed authentication flow. You may check this [Web API tutorial](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/quick-start/) quickstart from Spotify for Developers

**References:**

https://github.com/spotify/web-api-auth-examples/blob/master/client_credentials/app.js
https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/code-flow/
https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/quick-start/

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to get started, thank you so much!