# FetchingURL Using JSON on Google Sheets v3

Tags: json, google-apps-script, spotify

I have a code in JSON in Google Apps Scripts that takes a Spotify URL and pastes the amount of followers in the cell where you reference the url, for example =SAMPLE(A2) (where A2 holds the URL)

The value being returned is blank, and no error message is prompted. I have tried using a Spotify API, but this is impossible when taking data from a Spotify account that you don't own (from my understanding at least).

Here's the original post = [FetchingURL Using JSON on Google Sheets v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73576034/fetchingurl-using-json-on-google-sheets-v2)

Here's the code I have currently in Google Apps Scripts. (courtesy of @Tanaike)

```
function SAMPLE(url) {
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  const v = res.match(/<script id\="initial-state" type\="text\/plain">([\s\S\w]+?)<\//);
  if (!v || v.length != 2) return "Value cannot be retrieved.";
  const obj = JSON.parse(Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(v[1].trim())).getDataAsString());
  const value = Object.entries(obj.entities.items).reduce((n, [k, o]) => {
    if (k.includes("spotify:playlist:")) n.push(o.followers.total);
    return n;
  }, []);
  return value.length > 0 ? value[0] : "Value cannot be retrieved.";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your showing script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
if (k.includes("spotify:playlist:")) n.push(o.followers.total);
```

#### To:

```
if (k.includes("spotify:playlist:")) n.push(o.followers);
```

- It seems that the specification of the JSON object has been changed.

Comment: Oh great that seemed to do it! Thanks! Where did you see that it was followers instead of followers.total? Thanks!

Comment: @devR Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About `Where did you see that it was followers instead of followers.total?`, in this case, I checked the value of `obj`. By this, I could know it.